# mysql group by on unique combination of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table: `Employee`

```
columns:
1. id
2. name
3. city1
4. city2
```

I want to `GROUP BY` the combination of `city1` and `city2` so that e.g.

- an employee with city1: `'Bangalore'` and city2: `'Chennai'`
- and another employee with city1: `'Chennai'` and city2: `'Bangalore'`

comes in a single group when done `GROUP BY`.

Help me construct this sql.

Comment: You have to explain the aggregation a litle more, show some more data and desire output. What mean `comes in a single group`

Comment: Why wouldn't "SELECT * FROM Employee GROUP BY City1+City2" work?  It does for me.  Of course assume for now that the data is clean and there are no nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(city1, city2) as city1, greatest(city1, city2) as city2, count(*)
from employees
group by least(city1, city2), greatest(city1, city2);
```

The logic is slightly more complex if you have `NULL` values.  The question says nothing about `NULL` values.

Note:

This answer was edited to use:

```
group by city1, city2
```

Although technically correct, I removed the edit for two reasons:

1. `city1` and `city2` are ambiguous, because they are both the names of columns in the data and column aliases.
2. Not all databases support column aliases in the `group by` clause.

The first is the primary reason.  If the column aliases were different from names in the tables, then the alternative formulation would be fine.  Otherwise, I consider the code to be confusing and hence less maintainable and more prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a ordered key with your city and group it, using a `CASE WHEN`;

```
SELECT 
  CityKey,
  Id, 
  Name,
  count(CityKey)
FROM
  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN City1 > City2 THEN Concat(City1,City2)
         WHEN City1 <= City2 THEN Concat(City2,City1)
    END AS CityKey,
    Sample.City1,
    Sample.City2,
    Id,
    name
  FROM SAMPLE) WithKeys
GROUP BY CityKey, Id, Name;
```

Comment: This is not safe, e.g. cities ("AB", "C") and ("A", "BC"), both will get key "ABC". If you concat you need a delimiter that is not used in any city name.

Comment: and doesnt make sense you `group by id, name` those count will be 1 for every employee

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  yes it doesn't make sense, it's only an example to show Rajesh my approach

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT city,  count(*)
 FROM 
   (
    SELECT e.*,
           if(e.city1 < e.city2, 
              concat(city1,'-', city2),
              concat(city2,'-', city1)) as city
    FROM employee
   ) T
 GROUP BY city
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.